# Sync photos in iPhone to new PC

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos

Sometime back I have synced my iPhone with My Pictures folder in a PC.
That PC is now gone.
I dont have those photos anywhere but in my phone.
I can't see them from iTunes when connect my phone to PC.
I can't see them thru Windows Explorer.
I can't delete them in my phone.
When I try to turn on iCloud Photo Library, it says 1600+ photos will be removed.
I would like to copy them to my PC and delete them all from my phone. How do I that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Photo Gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-live/photo-gallery) [freeware - part of Microsoft Essentials] to import pictures from an iPhone/Pad to a Windows PC.

> **To import photos from a camera, phone or other device, CD, or DVD**
>
> 1. Make sure that your device is turned on and connected to your PC, or that the disc is inserted into your PC's CD or DVD drive.
> 2. Open Photo Gallery.
> 3. Click the Home tab, and then click Import.
> 4. In the Import Photos and Videos dialog box, click the device that you want to use, and then click Import. If you're importing from a CD or DVD, select the CD or DVD drive.
> 5. Click More options to select the options that you want to use, such as where to save the files and what format to use for the folder and file names.
> 6. Click one of the following two options: Review, organize and group items to import or Import all new items now.
>
> **Review, organize, and group items to import**
>
> 1. Click Review, organize and group items to import, and then click Next.
> 2. Define, select, and name the groups that you want to import:
>
>    - Photos are automatically grouped according to when they were taken. To change the time interval used to define the groups, at the bottom of the window, move the Adjust groups slider.
>    - To choose which groups of photos to import, next to each group, select the check box.
>    - To see all of the photos in a group, next to the group, click View all items. If you don't want to import all of the photos in the group, clear the check boxes for the photos that you don't want to import.
>    - For each group of photos that you want to import, click Enter a name, and then type a name for the group.
>    - To assign tags to a group, next to the group, click Add tags, type one or more tags separated by semicolons, and then press Enter.
>
>    Click Import. Each group of photos is saved to a different folder.
>
> **Import all new items now**
>
> 1. Click Import all new items now, and then type a name for the photos or videos.
> 2. To assign tags to the group of photos that you're importing, click Add tags, type one or more tags separated by semicolons, and then press Enter.
> 3. Click Import.
>
> **To add other folders of photos into Photo Gallery (for example, from OneDrive or from another location on your PC)**
>
> 1. Click File, and then click Include folder.
> 2. Click Add, and then select the folder you want to add to Photo Gallery.
> 3. Click Include folder, and then click OK.

Comment: Photo Gallery can't see the images which I can't see from Windows Explorer.